# Persisting Process steps and artifacts when following DDD with EF

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

We have an application where one feature is the generation of an output, a PowerPoint slide to be precise. The process of generating the output goes through a number of steps before the final output is created.

We have a requirement to record each step and optionally the artifacts (binaries) generated at each step ultimately to help end users and support to diagnose problems.

We have been following a DDD approach for the rest of the application and it has been a journey but I am conflicted on the approach for this requirement.

My initial approach is for a each request by the user to generate a PowerPoint to be DocumentRequest which will be an aggregate root. The question I have is how to represent the steps and their associated artifacts. Then have separate aggregate for the steps as I can’t see any invariant that would been to be enforced through the request. The DocumentRequest wouldn’t have a collection of Steps. Each step has a foreign key back to the request.

The closet similarity I can think of is the way VSTS represents a release or build. Each build /release consists of the steps along with each one having the option to download an artifacts or drilling into a textual log.

Comment: A domain with no business rules/invariants and little collaborativeness/concurrent access isn't the kind of context where you'll get the most out of the DDD tactical patterns. I would probably reconsider using them at all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert in DDD, but I agree - `DocumentRequest` does not look as a good aggregate root to me either. I'm asking myself a question - can `DocumentRequest` be defined without knowing the steps the generation process passed through? To me it certainly can. Can it be defined without the `Result` of the generation? Again, it can.

It looks like the process itself is quite important - you'd like to be able to view the artifacts for different steps. So I'd look at making the `DocumentGenerationProcess` (or use the better term if you'll find one) to be the aggregate root. Its going to have steps with artifacts referenced by each step, and probably the final result (the PowerPoint slide).

Another way you could model this - have `DocumentGenerationProcessResult` as an aggregate root. Normally it will contain the generated document (if the result is success). `DocumentGenerationProcessResult` will have a reference to the `GenerationProcess` with steps/artifacts, if users want to drill down into the details.